# LD_LIBRARY_PATH ignored by Python 2.7

Tags: python, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to install Theano on a box for which I have no root access and it looks like that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is ignored by my installation of Python 2.7. Since I can't install packages at the system level, I decided to compile all the packages (Python, SciPy, OpenBLAS, and others) from source and install them to $HOME. While testing SciPy, I got the error `ERROR: Failure: ImportError (libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)` but it looks like the library is present and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to the correct folder. Here's the complete transcript:

```
wheatstone-acogliat 42% echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/seas/grad/acogliat/lib

wheatstone-acogliat 43% python -c "import scipy; scipy.test()"
Running unit tests for scipy
NumPy version 1.9.3
NumPy is installed in /home/seas/grad/acogliat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
SciPy version 0.16.0
SciPy is installed in /home/seas/grad/acogliat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy
Python version 2.7.10 (default, Sep 28 2015, 21:06:05) [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)]
nose version 1.3.7
/home/seas/grad/acogliat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py:95: DeprecationWarning: `scipy.weave` is deprecated, use `weave` instead!
  warnings.warn(depdoc, DeprecationWarning)
E.......................................................................K.......................................................................................................EEEEEEEEE.....................................................................................................EE......................................................................S...........EEE...........................................K......................................................................................................
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/seas/grad/acogliat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/seas/grad/acogliat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/seas/grad/acogliat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/seas/grad/acogliat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/cluster/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import vq, hierarchy
  File "/home/seas/grad/acogliat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/cluster/vq.py", line 89, in <module>
    from . import _vq
ImportError: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[...MULTIPLE SIMILAR ERRORS OMITTED...]

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=2, SKIP=1, errors=15)

wheatstone-acogliat 44% ls -al $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
total 47232
drwxr-sr-x  6 acogliat eestudent      512 Sep 28 22:58 ./
drwxr-sr-x 19 acogliat eestudent      512 Sep 28 23:29 ../
drwxr-sr-x  3 acogliat eestudent      512 Sep 28 22:58 cmake/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 acogliat eestudent       30 Sep 28 22:58 libopenblas.a -> libopenblas_opteronp-r0.2.14.a
-rw-r--r--  1 acogliat eestudent 25211324 Sep 28 22:57 libopenblas_opteronp-r0.2.14.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 acogliat eestudent 12826920 Sep 28 22:57 libopenblas_opteronp-r0.2.14.so*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 acogliat eestudent       31 Sep 28 22:58 libopenblas.so -> libopenblas_opteronp-r0.2.14.so*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 acogliat eestudent       31 Sep 28 22:58 libopenblas.so.0 -> libopenblas_opteronp-r0.2.14.so*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 acogliat eestudent 10193546 Sep 28 21:36 libpython2.7.a*
drwxr-sr-x  3 acogliat eestudent      512 Sep 28 22:46 perl5/
drwxr-sr-x  2 acogliat eestudent      512 Sep 28 21:36 pkgconfig/
drwxr-sr-x 28 acogliat eestudent    14336 Sep 28 21:36 python2.7/

wheatstone-acogliat 45% uname -a
Linux wheatstone 2.6.18-404.el5 #1 SMP Tue Apr 7 12:42:54 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @meuh that was it! My shell was set to csh, which I'm not very familiar with. Thanks so much! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: ah, csh! very different to the bourne shell. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is explicitly calling `dlopen()` to find files it will
use LD_LIBRARY_PATH, though normal
python uses `$PYTHONPATH` to find modules and libraries. You can also set
the `sys.path` array:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/mydir')
```

Remember to export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both `$PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path` with the same error. It looks like the only way to fix the problem is to issue an `ldconfig`, which I can't do because I have no root access.